# Find dataframe rows which specific cells fulfill specific regex expressions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

Lets say I have Pandas dataframe:

```
data_df:

color          shape          number

green 5        triangle       3
green 1056     rectangle      2
blue           square         1
blue           circle         5
blue           square         4
```

and I have other dataframe with these filter parameters:

```
filter_df:

color          shape          number

green .*       ANY            ANY
blue           square         1
```

Result after filtering should be:

```
filtered_data_df:

color          shape          number

blue           circle         5
blue           square         4
```

My erroneous approach was to create regex expressions for color, shape and number such that:

```
color_regex = 'green .*|blue'
shape_regex = '.*|square'  # I would replace ANY with '.*'
number_regex = '.*|1'
```

After that I would simply use:

```
filtered_data_df = data_df.drop(
           data_df[data_df['color'].str.match(color_regex , case=False)].index &
           data_df[data_df['shape'].str.match(shape_regex , case=False)].index &
           data_df[data_df['number'].astype(str).str.match(number_regex, case=False)].index,
           axis=0)
```

but of course, because I have '.*' in both shape_regex and number_regex, everything would be filtered out, and I want everything to be filtered out just for color green and for blue just the combination of blue/square/1.

I could probably write something, but that would involve some kind of FOR loop, which, working with Pandas, I assume I can skip using.

In my real case, data_dt can have up to 5000 rows, and filter_dt can have ~100 rows (3 columns) of filtering parameters combinations, with constant potential to grow further (row-wise).

My question is, how to handle this filtering in some efficient Pandas way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use list comprehension. I should note that `df` is your `data_df` and `df1` is your `filter_df`

```
# replace any with .*
df1 = df1.replace('ANY', '.*')
# zip your columns
z = zip(df1['color'], df1['shape'], df1['number'])

# list comprehension with logic and str.contains
l = [~((df['color'].str.contains(c)) &\
       (df['shape'].str.contains(s)) & \
       (df['number'].astype(str).str.contains(n))).values for c,s,n in z]

# numpy.equal to see where the true values overlap then use boolean indexing
df[np.equal(*l)]

  color   shape  number
3  blue  circle       5
4  blue  square       4
```

here is the sample data

```
s = """color,shape,number
green 5,triangle,3
green 1056,rectangle,2
blue,square,1
blue,circle,5
blue,square,4"""

s1 = """color,shape,number
green .*,ANY,ANY
blue,square,1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1))
```